# SEOMoz: Domain Authority not increasing after moving domain

Tags: seo, seo-audit

I have recently moved from `old-domain.example` to `new-domain.example`. I have tried to follow all best practices and `old-domain.example` currently does a 301 to `new-domain.example`

My ranking has not suffered too much from the move.

However, my *domain authority* was 14 on `old-domain.example` and 2 months after the move, it is still 1 on `new-domain.example`

More surprisingly, the DA has increased on `old-domain.example` and have now reached 17.

What is the reason for that and can I expect my new domain's DA to increase in the coming months? Is it a matter of time or did I miss something?

I will add that I have made my best to update backlinks to point to `new-domain.example` and I've created new backlinks to `new-domain.example` in the past month.

Comment: You do realise that Moz's matrix is an internal thing and not something that Google uses? it predicts, nothing more. Also, its not real time, additionally to a new domain will lose all your DA, Domain authority can take years to establish. One of the biggest factors of DA is AGE, your site is now only 2 months old. Did you 301 old to new domain? if yes, the its simply because MOZ hasn't updated.

Comment: Whenever you move your content to a new domain name, you are moving from an established domain with trust and authority scores to a domain that does not have these metrics and must earn them. The 301 redirect only effects the individual page authority and not the site authority. You will have have to, in effect, start over in developing your sites trust and authority- the major factor is site age. This is why I recommend NOT changing domain names. Any advantage sought in the new domain name will not outweigh the loss of authority.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about Moz's Domain Authority here. There are lots of factors that go into it. It may be a matter of time, it could also be a number of other factors. https://moz.com/learn/seo/domain-authority

Ultimately, though, whatever your DA score is doesn't matter so much...it is an indicator of success, not something Google or Bing uses. Even Moz says in that article "The best way to influence this metric is to improve your overall SEO."

Given that, I'm more curious how your domain is performing in Google or Bing following the move. You mentioned rankings are holding, but what about traffic from search and the quality of that traffic? Did any rankings increase or decrease? What changes can you make to increase rankings? What can you do to improve decreased rankings?

As well, what do Bing Webmaster Tools or Google Search Console have to say - are there any new errors or issues, what does search analytics show, what about the count of indexed pages? (For more on Google Search Console and what to check out, you may find this video helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7iSlnD6sEM)

Basically, my point is that Domain Authority is something interesting and helpful to look at to give you an idea of overall comparison to other domains. I use it often with my clients, especially related to link building. But, Moz's DA isn't something I'd really worry about or focus on improving. It really isn't the sign that your site move worked or not. If rankings, traffic, traffic quality, errors, indexed pages, etc. are all doing well (or improving) following the move, then that will tell you if the domain move worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this as I felt the same. I was expecting the previous DA to transfer over to the clients new domain. However I'd also forgotten this isn't a google thing it's a moz thing.

We took the client from `www.example1.com` to `www.example2.com` although the domain authority has been reading like a brand new domain, we are still getting the traffic from before from the 301 redirects and with the new website and newsletter we've been seeing better traction and positive feedback from the new site. This isn't viewable in the DA reading.

Interestingly the stats previously were coming from pieces of content that were neglected and didn't represent the brand or do much to drive conversion. Removing the dead rot of old content and rebranding the website requires snapping off some of the things that previously looked good in overall stats but didn't ultimately deliver. You've got to know what you're breaking off.

You need to understand how the website is working on different levels and rely on other measures other than the DA. Understand which content has been removed and which added - focusing to drive the new content.

I also figure that if the website previously relied too much on its age for the DA, then it wasn't a very good website from an SEO perspective. This could also logically be the reason why the previous DA didn't transfer over.